# How to insert and select query at the same time in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

I have one table name `Blog` and i insert data on the table by using tne next query

```
INSERT INTO `blog`(title,desc) VALUES ('blog1','description')
```

And then i select data from the table by using

```
SELECT * FROM `blog`
```

This gives two hit to the database. Is there any possible way to do both queries at the same time. I want to make the process with one hit to the database.

Comment: I really  don't understand what is the target of your query. whay is the propuse for that?

Comment: `desc` is a reserved word, so I doubt that this is your query. Anyway, you cannot combine a SELECT with an INSERT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suppose you can use below statement :

> INSERT INTO `blog`(title,desc) VALUES ('blog1','description') SELECT *
>   FROM `blog` ;

Comment: `INSERT INTO blog(title,desc) VALUES ('blog1','description'); SELECT * FROM blog`. It is working for me thank you

Comment: He asks multi_query. It is not insert values.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the document

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

if (!$mysqli->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test") || !$mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE test(id INT)")) {
    echo "Table creation failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS _num FROM test; ";
$sql.= "INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (1); ";
$sql.= "SELECT COUNT(*) AS _num FROM test; ";

if (!$mysqli->multi_query($sql)) {
    echo "Multi query failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

do {
    if ($res = $mysqli->store_result()) {
        var_dump($res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
        $res->free();
    }
} while ($mysqli->more_results() && $mysqli->next_result());
?>
```